# date difference in HSQLDB

Tags: sql, oracle, hsqldb

I am converting my oracle query to hsqldb query, i face issue while using date difference in where clause as follows.

```
select ... where...
AND  90 - (to_date(sysdate) - to_date(substr(last_accessed_time_stamp,1,instr(last_accessed_time_stamp, ' ')),'YYYY-MM-DD')) in (1,3,5)
```

I need this condition to work in both oracle and hsqldb. Please let me know how it can be done

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the data type of the last_accessed_time_stamp column?

Comment: it is varchar data type

Answer (score 0):

A condition that works in HSQLDB is as follows:

```
AND 90 DAY - (sysdate - to_date(substr(last_accessed_time_stamp,1,instr(last_accessed_time_stamp, ' ')),'YYYY-MM-DD')) DAY in (1 DAY,3 DAY,5 DAY)
```